# jquery ajax filter chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to have a chain of filters (mostly in cases of errors) which are called sequentially and are given the xhrObject, so that each filter function can decide what to do based on the specific fault. There should also be a mechanism for passing along the data to the next filter function, or stopping the chain at some point.

I know that the Deferred objects in jQuery allow something like that, but I don't really see a way to declare one global xhrObject, to which these filter callbacks will hook up at the very beginning, so that they are handling any response/fault. Besides, having one global service delegate is not good either, because it may make the app go out of sync if the users perform many operations, while the previous ones haven't finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Besides, having one global service delegate is not good either,
>   because it may make the app go out of sync if the users perform many
>   operations, while the previous ones haven't finished yet.

AJAX, by its nature, is asynchronous. You should program accordingly. There is nothing wrong with a single delegation AJAX function.

```
I'd like to have a chain of filters
```

I think you need to explain this portion a little more clearly.